# Encoding problems while writing a text using delphi

Tags: php, delphi, unicode, encoding

I'm writing a php file, but got a problem on this exact line

```
Writeln(f,'<(meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /)>');
/note i used a coupla extra ( )
```

That writes the head of my webpage.

If i takes it out, all characters go on smoothly `(Ç, é, ó, some others)`
But this line is necessary to the webpage.

Don't know what to do =/

Comment: Just to be sure ... You have problems with unicode?

Comment: The written output will not become magically UTF8 just by writing this header line. Depending on your Delphi version you write ANSI or UTF16 but never UTF8 out of the box. You have to ensure to write the strings in UTF8 encoding

Answer (score 3):

If you have a "new" Delphi (2009+) You could se a TStringlist to build your php file

```
var
  myPhpFile: TStringlist;
begin
  myPhpFile := TStringlist.Create;
  try
    myPhpFile.Add('<(meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /)>');
    myPhpFile.SaveToFile('myFile.php', TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    myPhpFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are writing files using `Writeln` which is legacy Pascal I/O. This does not support Unicode and you'll need to write the file using a different method.

The obvious way to do so is with a stream writer class:

```
Output := TFileStream.Create(...);
Writer := TStreamWriter.Create(Output, TEncoding.UTF8);
Writer.WriteLine(
  '<(meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /)>'
);
```

The encoding parameter passed to the writer's constructor ensures that the writer encodes the text using the correct text encoding, UTF-8 in this case.

---

As Jan points out, this will emit a BOM, which you don't want. So you can derive an encoding class that does not emit a BOM.

```
type
  TUTF8EncodingWithoutBOM = class(TUTF8Encoding)
  public
    function GetPreamble: TBytes; override;
  end;

function TUTF8EncodingWithoutBOM.GetPreamble: TBytes;
begin
  Result := nil;
end;
```

Create a single global instance of this class at initialization, and pass it to the stream writer.

Comment: Does this also write a BOM?

Comment: I wonder why it writes a BOM by default. For UTF-8, the recommendation is not to write one, IIRC. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) says: "The Unicode Standard permits the BOM in UTF-8, but does not require or recommend its use".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis For historic reasons, BOMs seem to prevail on Windows.

Comment: For UTF-16, but I'm not so sure about UTF-8.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis For UTF-8 too. Most Windows tools expect BOMs.